# How to have a Server Socket broadcast that it's there, and have a client socket detect it and connect

Tags: java, sockets, broadcast, lan

I think we've all played Minecraft before, and know that it can have a local server detection. A lot of games do it, where one player hosts a game, and another can connect just because it's on the same network. I'm wondering, how would you code something like this in java? How does a server on minecraft broadcast itself to the network, and how does the client find and connect to it? If this is the wrong place to put this, i'm sorry I didn't know, but I feel it might be.

How do you have a socket broadcast that it's there and connectable, and have another socket find and connect to it, the same way a lan game works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PulsePanda, the logic can be implemented using Multicasting. Using this protocol you can broadcast a message to machines in a LAN. Another example of this implementation is IPMsg. You can find more information about multicast [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast). JDK 7 comes with built-in multicast [socket](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html). You can also find detailed example at following [location](http://lycog.com/programming/multicast-programming-java/).